# How to calculate Moreau-Broto autocorrelation, Moran autocorrelation, Geary autocorrelation from protein (amino acid) sequences?

Tags: python, gene, proteins, literature-search

I want to code Moreau-Broto autocorrelation, Moran autocorrelation, Geary autocorrelation in Python 3.6 from the scratch for amino acid sequences without using any package. Unfortunately, I have not been able to come across a proper literature which shows how these autocorrelation indices have to be calculated. Can anyone give a clear explanation as to how to calculate it or at least give a link which has got a clear description of how to calculate these?

Answer (score 2):

Rajarshi Guha describes the formulas to calculate [Moreau Broto autocorrelation, Moran coefficient and Geary coefficient](http://www.rguha.net/writing/notes/desc/node2.html) and has a [bibliography](http://www.rguha.net/writing/notes/desc/node8.html).

But why reinvent the wheel? It seems that the [Autocorrelation module](http://pybiomed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/Autocorrelation.html) of the [PyBioMed](http://pybiomed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package does already what you want: it is a pure Python implementation without any external dependencies.

Comment: its for python 2.7, not 3.6